# Cost of multiple instantiations

Tags: c#, instantiation

While working in a project today, I came across the following code:

```
pcShowByCategory.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div id='lblDivP'>"));
pcShowByCategory.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<table width=100%><tr><td colspan='2' align ='left'>"));
pcShowByCategory.Controls.Add(lblTitle);
pcShowByCategory.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</br>"));
pcShowByCategory.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</br>"));
pcShowByCategory.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td></tr><tr><td colspan='2'>"));
pcShowByCategory.Controls.Add(lbltitle1);
pcShowByCategory.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</br>"));
pcShowByCategory.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td></tr><tr><td colspan='2'>"));
```

My initial thought was: why in the world didn't they do this in one or two lines instead of creating so many new LiteralControls.
My question is - is this sloppy and wasteful of memory, and should have been consolidated to one or two instantiations of LiteralControl, or is this not a big deal?

Comment: I saw that, and edited - thanks

Comment: or highlight code block and hit to 101 010 button in the formatting bar.

Comment: Maybe they were used to Java Servlets out.println'ing each line :P

Answer (score 1):

if they are all hard coded string then someone should be fired.

The bare minimum 10 second refactor...

```
pcShowByCategory.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div id='lblDivP'><table width=100%><tr><td colspan='2' align ='left'>"));
pcShowByCategory.Controls.Add(lblTitle);
pcShowByCategory.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</br></br></td></tr><tr><td colspan='2'>"));
pcShowByCategory.Controls.Add(lbltitle1);
pcShowByCategory.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</br></td></tr><tr><td colspan='2'>"));
```

...is still pretty rubbish but not quite so blood curdling.

Still screening for a rethink though.

Comment: yes, that is precisely what I was thinking - but what of resource usage? is this a bad practice just because of sloppy coding technique, or a bad practice because of potential real-world performance loss (if this type of poor coding is used everywhere)?

Comment: @Ron: the performance-impact of sloppy code is hard to determine by looking solely at the raw code itself.  The compiler is quite good at optimizing performance and as a result it's often better to write readable code than to try to hand-optimize relatively simple coding structures.  This example falls under the "needlessly sloppy" category though--but in general you can't jump to conslusions with evidence of the performance impact--that's just premature optimization.